# How to inject Spring bean in Google App Engine

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, inversion-of-control

I have problem with injecting Spring bean in GAE app.

In Servlet I have property controlled by IOC contener. My **web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<web-app
    version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>update</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.servlet.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>update</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/update</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

and **applictionContext.xml**:

```
<beans>

    <bean class="com.myapp.servlet.MyServlet">
        <property name="webServicePort" ref="webServicePort"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="webServicePort" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean" scope="singleton" >
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.ws.generated.WebServicePortType" />
        <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="http://endpoint/doc.wsdl" />
        <property name="namespaceUri" value="namespace" />
        <property name="serviceName" value="WebService" />
        <property name="endpointAddress" value="http://endpoint/soap.php" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

In this case, during contex creating, `webServicePort` bean was injected to Servlet. But when I sent first request, field was null.

When I changed Spring descriptor to inject by constructor argument:

```
<beans>

    <bean class="com.myapp.servlet.MyServlet">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="webServicePort"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="webServicePort" class="org.springframework.remoting.jaxws.JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean" scope="singleton" >
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.ws.generated.WebServicePortType" />
        <property name="wsdlDocumentUrl" value="http://endpoint/doc.wsdl" />
        <property name="namespaceUri" value="namespace" />
        <property name="serviceName" value="WebService" />
        <property name="endpointAddress" value="http://endpoint/soap.php" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

bean `MyServet` was created with `webServicePort` injected in constructor. But after request sent to Servlet I got:

```
[INFO] java.lang.InstantiationException: com.myapp.servlet.MyServlet
[INFO]  at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
[INFO]  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
(...)
```

I added logging both in setter and constructor of `Servlet` class. I got only once message in server logs. I understand what is going on, but I don't know why...

Correct me, if I'm wrong. During getting up application context, `webServicePort` is creating and injecting to `Servlet`. But first request sending to it is creating new instance of `Servlet`, without injected beans, right? But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you have an spring context that is not aware of the http requests, it means that when a request arrives the servlet container use its own MyServlet instance, instead of get one from the spring context.

To correct this issue, you need to make that your class implements [org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/HttpRequestHandler.html) instead of HttpServlet,
which is its analogous within the spring world.

Something like:

```
public class MyServlet implements HttpRequestHandler {


  private JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean  webServicePort;

  public void setWebServicePort(JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean  webServicePort){
      this.webServicePort=webServicePort
  }

  @override
  public void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
      //request management 
  }
}
```

Then add the servlet definition within the deployment descriptor web.xml

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>update</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>update</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/update</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And add the servlet name within the applicationContext.xml as bean id, take special care that the bean id match the servlet name defined within the web.xml:

```
<bean id="update" class="com.myapp.servlet.MyServlet">
    <property name="webServicePort" ref="webServicePort"/>
</bean>
```

This post may can help you:
http://andykayley.blogspot.com/2008/06/how-to-inject-spring-beans-into.html